# How can I prove an inequality related to fractional linear transformations?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, mobius-transformation

> Let $z$ and $w$ be complex values such that $|z| \leq 1, |w| \leq 1$ and $|\bar{z}w| \neq 1$, prove that 
>   $$\left|\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{z}w}\right| \leq 1$$

I was trying to solve using Schwarz inequality but I got nowhere, first i noticed that $|wz| \leq 1$ and use that $|w-z| \leq 2$ then

$$
\left|\frac{w-z}{1-\bar{z}w}\right|
  = \frac{|w-z|}{\left|1-\bar{z}w\right|}
  \leq \frac{2}{\left|1-\bar{z}w\right|}
$$

but now i need to decrease $\left|1-\bar{z}w\right|$ to improve the quotient but i only remember that $\left|1-\bar{z}w\right| \geq 1 -1 = 0$.

Comment: Why not expand $$|1-\bar zw|^2-|w-z|^2$$ using twice the identity $$|u|^2=u\bar u\ ?$$